# Panel Open close not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Hi I have requirement where Jquery mobile panel will be opening when some conditions are met i have tried close,open panel but that was not working. Please help Thanks in advance
http://jsfiddle.net/NFkE2/1/

```
<input id="fieldValue" type="text" name="fieldValue" placeholder="Type in an Value" size="90" />
<a href='#mypanel' onClick='javascript:check();' data-icon="flat-checkround" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-btn-mini">submit </a>

<div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-position-fixed="true" data-position="left" data-display="overlay" data-theme="d">
This is Panel! 
</div>
function check(){
var fieldValue = document.getElementById("fieldValue");
if(fieldValue.value==""){
    alert("closing panel");
 $( "#mypanel" ).panel( "close" , optionsHash );
}else{
$( "#mypanel" ).panel( "open" , optionsHash );
}
}
```

Comment: replace `href="#mypanel"` with `href="#"` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/NFkE2/9/

Answer (score 0):

Use this JavaScript code

```
function check(){
    var fieldValue = document.getElementById("fieldValue");
    if(fieldValue.value==""){
     $( "#mypanel" ).panel( "toggle" );
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NFkE2/8/)

Answer (score 0):

First, you should you look at your javascript console, as there are error warnings in it that could help you (for example, optionsHash is undefined). If you are not sure how to find the javascript console in your browser, you can do so with a quick Google search.

I made a new fiddle for you that I think accomplishes what you are trying to do: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthewcooley/M4Bfz/)

I've never used the JQuery mobile plugin, but I suspect this in your HTML:

```
<a href='#mypanel' onClick='javascript:check();' data-icon="flat-checkround" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-btn-mini">submit </a>
```

... is causing the panel to open whenever you click that submit text. In the Fiddle I made for you, clicking the panel will always close the panel, and clicking submit will always open the panel but with custom text based on whether your input is filled out or not. But you could use the same logic to either show or not show the panel depending on the input value.